# Second order PDE in 2 dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to find general solution of $u_{xx}+2(1-rx^2)u_y=0$ where $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$? Is there a particular method for solving equations of the following type
\begin{equation}
u_{xx}+f(x)u_y=0
\end{equation}